# Using Jetty in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, jetty, eclipse-juno

As I understand, Eclipse Juno release has Jetty servlet container embedded. So I have assumed, that means I can use Jetty in Eclipse Java EE without installing any additional plugins or packages. I have tried this:

- Created a simple dynamic Web project and run it on "J2EE Preview" Server. As a result I've got 404 error:

> Error 404 - Not Found
>
> No context on this server matched or handled this request. Contexts
>   known to this server are: ServletTest(/ServletTest)

- Tried to create embedded Jetty instance:

  ```
  public class Launcher {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          Server server = new Server(8080);
          server.start();
          server.join();
      }
  }
  ```

I am unable to find where can I import `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server` class from.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with your first approach. Looks like you're nearly there - you're just pinging the wrong URL. Try `http://localhost:8080/ServletTest`.

Comment: That is exactly what is open in my browser. As a result I get 404 as described above

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? Does your `ServletTest` class implement the correct API to respond to a request?

Comment: I am not following a tutorial. And I do hope my servlet is correct, having written them for the last 10 years :S But I will try to find some up-to-date tutorial for dummies for Eclipse Juno and web projects, in case I have missed something...

Comment: @Nikem sorry, didn't mean to imply you're a noob! Feel free to update the question when you've got a bit further.

Comment: Well, I really do seem like a noob right now :S. I have this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379180, which describes exactly my situation. But needed libraries, mentioned in that bug, are already installed in my Juno installation. So I am still at loss here...

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs currently in the J2EE preview which uses jetty. It seems that at this moment the Run-Jetty plugin is simply better imprelemnted...

http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/

If work perfectly for my web application, just using run as run-jetty